# How to list all colors in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, git-config

Is there an easy way to see all color settings configured for git? I can do a

```
git config -l | grep -F color
```

but given the many listing options in *git config*, I wonder whether there is a simpler way, not involving a pipe.

I tried

```
git config --get color
git config --get-all color
git config --get-color default
```

but the first two just complain that there is no section "color", and the last one doesn't produce any output. BTW, `git config --get-color added` or `git config --get-color status.added` also doesn't output anything, so I wonder how the --get-color option is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 2):

`git config --help` states that you can do:

```
git config --get-regexp color
```

This should be roughly equivalent to your command, without using a pipe.
(This only checks the config variable name though, so it does not find config variables whose values contain the string `"color"` unless it is also in the config variable name)